# jQuery move DOM element inside parent

Tags: jquery, element

Is there a simple way to move an element inside its own parent?

Like this...

from:

```
<div class="test">hello 1</div>
<div class="test">hello 2</div>
<div class="test">hello 3</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="test">hello 1</div>
<div class="test">hello 3</div>
<div class="test">hello 2</div>
```

Either move a div UP or DOWN one step, or using the index to appendTo in a specific position.

Comment: What are the characteristics of the two elements? How do you select the element to move, and where do you need to move it to?

Comment: I select it with a click handler. Then I use the index of the clicked element.

Comment: Okay, then where should the clicked element go? Should it be moved after the last element in the list? How do you determine the new position?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) like this (here as a jQuery function):

```
$.fn.moveUp = function() {
    $.each(this, function() {
         $(this).after($(this).prev());   
    });
};
$.fn.moveDown = function() {
    $.each(this, function() {
         $(this).before($(this).next());   
    });
};
$("div:eq(2)").moveUp(); //Would move hello 3 up
$("div:eq(0)").moveDown(); //Would move hello 1 down
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2ooooooo/HFtVJ/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("div:eq(2)").after($("div:eq(0)"));
```

or

```
$("div:eq(2)").before($("div:eq(1)"))
```

Remembering that :eq() is zero based.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `$("div:eq(2)").after($("div:eq(3)"))` or wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 3):

```
var child = $('#parent div'); // keep reference for further use
child.eq(2).insertBefore(child.eq(1));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AMNzJ/1/)**